# Searching Some string with "\" with powershell -match operator

Tags: powershell, path, registry, match

i need to check if some path exists in registry. 
I used powershell .
But i have a problem with "-match"

```
$reg1 = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\LunaClient\win32;C:\Program File
s\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit"
```

And when i used -match operator :

```
$reg1 -match "\Windows Kits\10"
```

or

```
$reg1 -match "\Windows Kits\10"
```

I getting "false"

I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “match”operator uses regular expressions whereas the “like” operator will allow you to use wildcards. If you switch to “like” and put the * symbol around it you should start getting your matches.

```
$reg1 -like "*\Windows Kits\10*"
```

Alternatively, if you’re really wanting to use regex, you would need to escape your slashes in the string you’re searching for. It’ll end up looking something like this:

```
$reg1 -match "\\Windows Kits\\10"
```

Comment: First method it's working  but second :    $reg1 -match "\/\Windows Kits/\10\" not,  -illegal \ at  end, and without \ at end also not works

Comment: Whoops - looks like I was using the wrong slash direction for the escape character in regex. It should be fixed now

Comment: Thanks now it's working :)  but alternative method must be withour "\" at end ;)

Comment: Needless to say I prefer the “like” operator :P

Answer (score 1):

Backward slash is a special character in regex. In regex you have to escape special character using backward slash.
Ex.

```
'C:\Windows' -match '\\Windows'
True
```

In your case..

```
$reg1 -match "\\Windows Kits\\10"
```